# Contact form doesn't send mail

Tags: 7, emails

I am using the contrib contact module to add a contact form.

I created a category in /admin/structure/contact to add the recipient. I added my person address mail (It's valid).

When I test the form, Drupal returns a confirm notification to say that the mail is send successfully.. But the mail is not received.

In /admin/reports/dblog, any error is reported.

PS: I use in my site other functions to send mail and it's received.

Any idea please?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) to create a contact form and mails are send